# What to do to keep implementation of calling another app if it does not exist in iOS device for appstore submission?

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment, app-store, release

I have an app that has a feature of calling WhatsApp and sending a text for a user to contact number automatically if WhatsApp was not found it will show a message stating that WhatsApp was not found and that user needs WhatsApp for the feature to work. After building the app and submitting it for review I got a reply from Apple:

> Your app should work on its own without requiring installation of another app to function.

Which is actually one of the review guidelines:
[Guideline 4.2.3](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

**Edit:**

The app is developed using react-native.

In the code I am doing this:

```
let url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + this.state.text + "&phone=" + this.state.phone
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((appAvailable) => {
  console.log(appAvailable)
    if(appAvailable) {
      Linking.openURL(url)
    } else {
      Alert.alert(LocalizationHelper.vocab.alerts.no_whatsapp_found_title, LocalizationHelper.vocab.alerts.no_whatsapp_found_msg, [
        {text: LocalizationHelper.vocab.alerts.no_whatsapp_found_btn, onPress: () => console.log('OK')}
      ]); 
    }
})
```

My question is what should be done to use this feature for sending a text from user's WhatsApp phone number without getting rejection from appstore?

Comment: They want to make sure the app has more to it than just being a wrapper for another app.  What other features does the app have?  You can build a pretty quick & easy chat feature of your own with Firebase or Twillio as a "no Whatsapp" fallback.

Comment: So does this means that WhatsApp API can't be used?

Comment: No just that it has to be able to do something if the user doesn't use WhatsApp..

Comment: Can you please give me an example? The app basically only uses the mentioned feature.

Comment: If the app only uses the mentioned feature it is not going to be allowed into the App Store. End of story.

Comment: As @BrandonStillitano said, you're going to need another feature.  As for examples, as I suggested, a chat app using Firebase or Twillio.